# Libre Office Labels don't show up as "AcroFields" in iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, itext, libreoffice

so I've been trying to generate a report. I've tried quite a few things already but there always seems to be problems. I'm currently trying iTextSharp 4.1.6.

My current strategy is to use LibreOffice to create a document with editable pdf fields, or I guess they are called "[AcroFields](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+acrofield+mean&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS795US795&oq=what+does+acrofield+mean&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.3368j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)". I'm not sure since I can't find a definition. But anyways, I assume that all of these are "AcroFields":

[image]

But if I put all of those into a form and export as pdf only some of them show up as AcroFields:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes("abc.pdf"));
foreach(var field in reader.AcroFields.Fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((DictionaryEntry)field).Key);
}

> Text Box 1
  Check Box 1
  Numeric Field 1
  Formatted Field 1
  Date Field 1
  List Box 1
  Combo Box 1
  Push Button 1
  Option Button 1
```

Notice how `Label Field 1` is not present. If it **were** present then doing a text replace might be easy. Except it's not present so it's looking like even iText can't do a simple text replace in a pdf. Is this true? How would you replace text in a pdf document using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

> Notice how Label Field 1 is not present.

As there is no **AcroForm** form field type "label", form *labels* usually are drawn as regular page content in PDF files.

> If it were present then doing a text replace might be easy. Except it's not present so it's looking like even iText can't do a simple text replace in a pdf. Is this true?

Indeed, in general there is no simple text replacement in a PDF.

> How would you replace text in a pdf document using iTextSharp?

I would determine the bounding box coordinates of the text to replace using the iText text extraction feature with some extension that returns text plus coordinates. Then I'd remove that text by redaction using iText's `PdfCleanUp...` classes. Finally I'd add the replacement text as new text in the bounding box determined at start.

Unfortunately for you, both good text extraction and redaction are not present in your version 4.1.6; for this approach you should update at least to 5.5.x.

Alternatively, though, as *you've been trying to generate a report*, I assume the template design is in your hands. In that case you can put your labels into read-only text fields which you *can* change (they are read-only only to GUI users).

Comment: I couldn't find a list of AcroField types anywhere. 4.1.6 is the newest free version so that's probably the end of the line for me with iTextSharp. Do you know if I did it that way, though, would it wrap the text (and update the document to reflect the wrap) or would it just g.DrawString right on top of the pdf? Using a read only text box isn't viable because that looks terrible. Yep, I have been *trying to generate a report*. The only working solution I have that doesn't generate crappy looking reports is to edit with OpenXML and then use LibreOffice command line arguments to convert to PDF.

Comment: Except that introduces all kinds of security headaches on a web server. I can get decent html->pdf conversions using tools that use headless webkit to generate the PDF but those are all command line too.

Comment: *"the newest free version"* - that **free** / **not free** division is very black and white; both that old version and newer versions offer you a library for free under specific conditions. The obligations before AGPL appear less demanding but the AGPL obligations can also be fulfilled and can be considered fair.

Comment: That being said, though,... *"Do you know if I did it that way, though, would it..."* - well, it would not re-flow the full layout (e.g. pushing the lines beneath the replacement area down to make more room etc) but you can of course use `ColumnText` for proper layout _in_ the determined bounding box.

Comment: *"The only working solution I have that doesn't generate crappy looking reports is to edit with OpenXML and then use LibreOffice command line arguments to convert to PDF."* - do you really need to prepare the report template in a WYSIWYG fashion? Otherwise, how about creating the report from scratch in iText, using `Paragraph`s, `PdfPTable`s, and their ilk which you add to an iText `Document`? Or if you prefer HTML, you could use the iText `HTMLWorker`; it does only support a small subset of HTML but it might suffice.

Comment: Are you sure it's free to use? On [github](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) they say you have to buy it as soon as you use it in a commercial application. So there is a `ColumnText` that will trigger a reflow? I'm actually extremely tempted to just code the thing in html and use a programmatic html->pdf converter. That seems like the best way. But what's holding me back is that isn't WYSIWYG because...idk why. That's probably what I'll do.

Comment: *"Are you sure it's free to use? On github they say you have to buy it as soon as you use it in a commercial application."* - If you use iText under AGPL, you essentially have to provide access to your source code to everyone who gets in contact with the program (not only the people running your program but also those e.g. retrieving output PDFs from it); for applications used inside a single organization only, this may be ok. Furthermore, you can always establish a commercial business model by consulting and support for the software. So what *they say on github* is somewhat simplified.

Comment: *"So there is a `ColumnText` that will trigger a reflow?"* - `ColumnText` will properly layout your new text inside the determined bounding box, including line breaks etc. It will *not* change any outer existing content, though.